# Automatic two way binding with Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm just getting started with Knockout.js and i have a view(html) which is supposed to be populated by data from a rest api via jquery's $.getJSON method.
When i run the app, nothing shows but using firebug i can see that the 'GET' query returns a status code of 200 and the right data.
I'm at a fix as to why nothing shows in the view since the bindings in Knockout.js are supposed to be automatic.
Below is my code. 
Thanks

```
<div id ='main'>
<!-- ko foreach: posts -->


    <p>Hello</p><span data-bind="text: title"></span></p><p data-bind="text: content"></p>
    <p data-bind="text: author"></p><p data-bind="text: date"></p>

<!-- /ko -->
</div>
</body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        function Post(data){
            this.title = ko.observable(data.title);
            this.content = ko.observable(data.content);
            this.author = ko.observable(data.author);
            this.date = ko.observable(data.date)
        }
        function PostListViewModel(){
            var self = this;
            self.posts = ko.observableArray([]);


            $.getJSON("/posts", function(getPost){
                var mappedPost = $.map(getPost, function(item){
                    return new Post(item)
                });
                self.posts(mappedPost);

            });
        }

    var postlistviewmodel = new PostListViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(postlistviewmodel);

</script>
```

[image: screenshot of my console]

Comment: take a look at my answer and the included fiddle, may help you understand what to do

Comment: Just built a fiddle around what you have done, please see.

Comment: @No1_Melman No not yet. I can see the results in the console so i'm very sure the 'GET' query works. Thanks

Comment: When i use the followings endpoint 'posts/<id>' it works. This is making me more confused

Comment: You don't need the model to have observables, i would honestly take them out. You're not trying to achieve two way binding with the post model are you?

Comment: I don't actually need the two way bindings and i've removed it

Answer (score 0):

This should be:

```
$.getJSON("/posts", function(getPost){
    var mappedPosts = $.map(getPost, function(item){
        return new Post(item)
    });

    self.posts(mappedPosts);
});
```

wouldn't do `self.posts.push(mappedPosts[i])` at all. You should just pass `mappedPosts` through the ko binding in order to update the listeners.

If your just getting the latest posts and want to update your current list simply do:

```
var allPosts = self.posts().concat(mappedPosts);
self.posts(allPosts);
```

You don't need the model to have ko.observable if you're just displaying them. If you want to edit model as well, then leave as.

Also, I tend to do this for single or multiple view models:

```
ko.applyBindings({viewModel : new viewModel() };
```

This allows for having multiple named view models. Access scope using: $root.viewModel

This is what I did earlier: http://jsfiddle.net/jFb3X/

Check your code against this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rd52S/1/) then.

Script tags also need to be above the closing body tags

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<!-- all your html content -->

<script type="text/javascript">
   var viewModel = function () {

   }
   ko.applyBindings({viewModel : new viewModel()});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this was the first thing i tried and it didn't work.

Comment: put in console.log everywhere to try and understand what is being retrieved etc. So put one before the json request to make sure it is being sent, put one inside to make sure it has been fired, put the `getPost` variable through the console log to see what information has come out. So on so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Is it something as simple as waiting for the DOM to be ready?

Are you able to try the following:

```
$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(postlistviewmodel);
});
```

Source: I've done this a few times and been stumped for a bit trying to see what I did wrong.  :-)

(As a style thing, I'd also move the /body to after the /script - probably not related to your issue though).

Comment: In my experience, putting ko into jQuery doc load doesn't change anything, mainly because it is designed to be used without!

Comment: No worries, to be honest, I used to always do it like that until I changed one day (don't know why)

Answer (score -2):

I suspect you get multiple posts from /posts. You only push a single item (array).

```
...
            $.getJSON("/posts", function(getPost){
                var mappedPosts = $.map(getPost, function(item){
                    return new Post(item)
                });
                for(var i = 0; i < mappedPosts.length; i++) {
                    self.posts.push(mappedPosts[i]);
                }

            });
...
```

Comment: I wouldn't do self.posts.push(mappedPosts[i]) at all, that bypasses the binding. You should just pass `mappedPosts` through the ko binding

Comment: That is easier, definitly. But it doesn't bypass the binding. Methods like push, splice and removeAll for instance all give change updates. (it is getting late ;))

Comment: @No1_Melman i added the push to self.posts when it did not work at first.

Comment: Why is the script tag outside of the body tag?